# Prove that $\langle 1,1 \rangle$ and $\langle 1,2 \rangle$ span $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

> Theorem 1.1 - If $A$ is a nonempty subset of a vector space $V$, then the set $L(A)$ of all linear combination of the vectors in $A$ is a subspace, and it is the smallest subspace of $V$ which includes the set $A$.

- Is my answer rigorous enough? I am wondering if I am relying on the given theorem 1.1 too much.
- Do I need to show that $A = \{ \langle 1,1 \rangle, \langle 1,2 \rangle\}$ is a subset of $V$ or is that already obvious enough?

**My answer:**
Suppose $A$ is a nonempty subset of vector space $V$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and contains the vectors $\langle 1,1 \rangle$ and $\langle 1,2 \rangle$. Then by Theorem 1.1, $L(A)$, the set of all linear combinations of the vectors in $A$ is a subspace in $V$ and is the smallest subspace that contains the vectors in $A$.

Thus we can call $L(A)$ the linear span, or subspace generated by the two vectors in $A$.

Comment: Show that every point in $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be written as linear combination of given vectors .

Comment: Your phrasing is confusing to me.  If you want to show that $\langle 1,1\rangle$ and $\langle 1,2\rangle$ span $\Bbb R^2$, then just talk about $L(\{\langle 1,1\rangle,\langle 1,2\rangle\})$.  If you prefer to call the set $A$ first, then great.  Phrasing it as "Suppose $A$ is non-empty... and contains the vectors..." is unnecessary and ambiguous.  The way you phrased it it sounds as though $A$ might have more vectors than those two that you mentioned.

Comment: As for actually proving the result you want, you haven't done anything but restated the result of your theorem $1.1$ and your attempt is incomplete.  It should be obvious that $L(A)$ is a subspace of $V$.  What remains to show is that $V$ is a subspace of $L(A)$ for your specific case, something which is not always going to be true in general and must be shown to be true here.

Comment: You have to show the span is $\Bbb R^2$, not some proper subspace

Comment: Note that, for instance, the vectors $\langle 1,1 \rangle$ and $\langle 2,2 \rangle$ do _not_ span $\Bbb R^2$. But your proof does nothing to distinguish this case from the one you started with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, your answer proves nothing. You are supposed to prove that every vector $(a,b)\in\mathbb R^2$ is a linear combination of $(1,1)$ and $(1,2)$. You can do that by proving that there are numbers $x,y\in\mathbb R$ such that $(a,b)=x(1,1)+y(1,2)=(x+y,x+2y)$. In other words, solve the system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}x+y=a\\x+2y=b.\end{array}\right.$$You will get $x=2a-b$ and $y=b-a$. Since every vector of $\mathbb R^2$ is a linear combination of $(1,1)$ and $(1,2)$ then, indeed, $\operatorname{span}\bigl\{(1,1),(1,2)\bigr\}=\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: So essentially we setup the system of equations to show the linear independence. Then the linear independence shows that the vectors span the vector space?

Comment: No. The fact the system always has *some* solution is equivalent to the assertion that the vectors span the whole space. Linear independence is equivalent to another assertion, namely that the system never has more than one solution.

Comment: Can you give a trivial example of a system with linear dependence that spans the whole space?

Comment: Sure: $\{(1,0),(0,1),(1,1)\}$ spans $\mathbb R^2$, but it's linearly dependent.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if $(1,1)$ and $(1,2)$ are in the span, then $(1,2)-(1,1)=(0,1)$ is in the span and so is $(1,1)-(0,1) = (1,0)$ in the span, i.e., the span contains both unit vectors and so must be the whole space.